# Need to get the filename from a blob storage in azure using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am trying to fetch the filename in a blob storage so as to use it in my script further. I tried using az storage blob list and list the blobs present there, but unsuccessful to.

Here's the command that I used:

```
az storage blob list --connection-string connstr --container-name "vinny/input/"
```

It threw error as The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.ErrorCode: InvalidUri

Seems like it would just take the container and not the folder in it. But when i tried:

```
az storage blob list --connection-string connstr --container-name "vinny"
```

It doesn't list the file but keeps on executing.

I need to get the filename that's inside vinny/input/

Anyone got any solution for it?

Comment: what you have used connection string in config file, it should be like this: <add key="ConnString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=******;AccountKey=*******;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"/>

Comment: @DhananjaySingh - the `az` command doesn't use a config file, so there is no `<add key...>` element. That's only for a a .net project.

Comment: @david - ok got it, i thought she is trying with dot net code

Comment: Try listing within container `vinny` - does that work? the `/input/` part isn't a container (there are no subfolders in blob storage) - that is really part of the name, with delimiter characters). Then you can try adding `--delimiter` or `--filter` to deal with those subfolders and specific patterns.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you for your solution. I used the --prefix option and got the result that I expected.

Comment: If your issue has been solved, you could add an answer for others to refer.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a --prefix option to it and was able to list the file the way I wanted. Here it goes:

```
az storage blob list --connection-string connstr --container-name "vinny" --prefix "Input/" --output table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cli> az storage blob list -c container_name  --account-name storage_accaunt_name --output=table --num-results=* | awk or cut
```

then you can parse txt file with awk and cut etc..

good luck